# Mail client application with arbitrary filter support

Tags: email, email-client

I'm looking for a way to retrieve my mail (with a desktop application or a web frontend or another way I can't think of) with support of arbitrary filters. This shall include *all* of the following criteria:

- full set of logical conjunction, disjunction and negation of (atomic) filter expressions and logical conjunction, disjunction and negation of already existing filters (i.e. reusability of easy filters in more complex filters)
- support to query all mail headers
- the whole set of IMAP operations as actions to be executed when the filter matches

In other words, I'm looking for an application implementing [sieve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_(mail_filtering_language)) or something very similar.

In order to be maintainable the filter specifications have to be usable by all the applications mentioned above. This means that the criteria has to be fulfilled by one server side solution (my own server or a possibly cost free service) or has be a solution consisting of clients all able to handle a portable filter specification. Creating a separate mail address with an individual domain on the server is not a problem!

I tried:

- aol.de: far away from arbitrary combinations of logical expressions
- posteo.de: no specification of arbitrary mail filters
- set up a mail server on Synology DSM 5.0 (no mail filter specification in the GUI, but possibly with configuration file - I've got to look into this)
- researched mail clients for Android 4.x:

  - K9-Mail: sieve support not implemented yet, requested on https://code.google.com/p/k9mail/issues/detail?id=451
  - CloudMagic: no filter specification facilities
- researched mail clients for Linux:

  - Thunderbird 31.x:

    - native facilities export in custom format which is not Sieve and doesn't seem to be too popular and therefore not too portable
    - Thunderbird Message Filter Import/Export add-on: stopped working in 3.1
    - quickFilters add-on 2.6.1: I guess sieve import and/or export function would be mentioned on https://addons.mozilla.org/thunderbird/addon/quickfilters/
  - evolution 3.10.x: discussed on https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=216959 (implementation pending), no plugins found
  - KMail: no possibilities for sieve usage found
- avelsieve plugin for squirrelmail: possibly interesing, not researched

Comment: For local solutions, do you restrict the operating system?

Comment: I am almost certain procmail is turing complete, and can do all this and more  -- if you have access to your mail server. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Procmail
However I am no expert on procmail.
It might even work on client end.

Really need to know your OS, and also comfortableness with editing text config files.

Comment: Please be more specific about your criteria. Applications like Thunderbird, KMail, Outlook, etc. all support local filtering. For e.g. mutt, which can't do it natively, procmail (already mentioned) is recommended.